# Obtener una porción de una determinada cadena de texto en java

Tags: java

me gustaría saber como puedo obtener una determinada porción de una cadena de texto en java, de una palabra introducida por el usuario. En el código que yo tengo, las únicas opciones que sé son con substring y subSquence. Pero por ejemplo, si quiero obtener los últimos 4 caracteres de la palabra que introduzca un usuario, como no sé el número de caracteres que va a tener, no podría seleccionar yo directamente la posición. No sé si hay alguna forma de que te cuente el número de caracteres que tiene la palabra introducida por el usuario y de ahí que obtenga los últimos 4 caracteres. No sé si me explico, inserto el código para que se vea más claro.

```
private static Scanner sc;

private static String pidePalabra() {
    
    System.out.printf("Introduce una palabra de más de 10 caracteres: ");
    return sc.nextLine();
    
}

private static void muestraInfo(String palabra) {
    
    System.out.printf("Primeros 4 caracteres: %s%n", palabra.substring(0,4));
    System.out.printf("Del caracter 2 al caracter 8 (ambos incluidos): %s%n", palabra.subSequence(1, 9));
    System.out.printf("Últimos 4 caracteres: %s%n");

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

sc = new Scanner (System.in);
String palabra = pidePalabra();
muestraInfo(palabra);
sc.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**string.length()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) : el método `length()` es una variable final que se aplica a los objetos de cadena. El método `length()` devuelve el número de caracteres presentes en la cadena.

```
System.out.printf("Últimos 4 caracteres: 
%s%n",palabra.substring(palabra.length()-4,palabra.length()));
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias @Dramaturgo!!